# How should I think about points of discontinuity of rational functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I am re-taking pre-calculus as an adult and I'm finding myself confused by my textbook's section on rational functions. The textbook contains the following passage:

[image: link]

Now, my question is, why do we have to say $x ≠ 3$ after applying these algebraic manipulations? The function $f(x) = x - 2$ is defined for $x = 3$, and by the previous algebraic argument, $x - 2 = \frac{x^2 - 5x + 6}{x - 3}$, so shouldn't the function $f(x) = {x^2 - 5x + 6}{x - 3}$ be defined for $x = 3$ too since these are actually the same function?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: What’s happening is that the two functions are not the same.  They are the same for all values of $x$ except for $x=3$.  Typically people get sloppy and simplify the rational expression and say it is $x-2$ but this is wrong.  It is $x-2$ when $x$ is not 3.

Comment: This seems like a conflation of two questions: one about discontinuity in general, and another about why this particular function has a discontinuity.

Comment: Thanks @sykhic, that's very helpful. Since it seems like naive rules of simplification aren't valid then, I'd like to know what the correct rules are. I guess the lesson is that formulas that can be algebraically found to be equal to the same formula don't necessarily denote the same function, but then I'm not clear on how to apply algebraic manipulations of functions in valid way.

Comment: @RandoMcRandom:  The problem you are encountering is that humans are lazy.  To be precise, when we simplify $\frac{x}{x}$ to 1 we should state that this is only valid when $x$ is not zero.  It’s tedious to keep saying this and so people don’t.   With experience you get used to such shortcuts.  The way to proceed, I think, is that when you do a simplification ask yourself: “For what values of x is this valid?”.  After a while you’ll just know and it won’t be a big deal.

Comment: @sykhic Great. That clears things up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a function, one has to define a value for each point in its domain. The textbook does not tell what is the domain of $f$, but talks about its "non permissible value". In fact $\frac {x^2-5x+6} {x-3}$ is not defined on $x=3$, because this is $0/0$ which is undefined. So the domain of definition of $f$ is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\}$.

So when simplifying the rational fraction by $x-3$, you can then tell two stories:

- Define $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\; g(x)=x-2$. Then $f$ and $g$ are different, because their domain of definition is not the same.
- Define $h: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\} \to \mathbb{R}, \;h(x)=x-2$. Then $f$ and $h$ are equal.

Note that you may encounter a subtlety that complicates things: when talking about rational fractions, $\frac {X^2-5X+6} {X-3} = X-2$. This is because here people do not talk any more about a function, but about a quotient of two polynomials, that is an algebraic object. It has its own life, so to say, independantly of functions. So simplification in this case is correct.

(And by the way, as commented by @AnotherUser, you should write the text in the picture into some real text; notably because that's better for impaired people).